# is there a short way to build a recipe for Yocto with a list of packages?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I hav already a linux system running in an ubuntu distro, specifically compiled for a hummingboard (imx6); the system runs stably but since we are extending its functionality, we need to change the board.
The new board has more hardware and connections available, but it runs on a yocto distribution provided by SoC the manufacturer.

I am trying to port my programs inside the new board, but given that the programs use many different libraries, I will have to add them one by one on Yocto recipe and recompile the image/repository again and then recompile my program.

I just obtained a list of all dependencies (ubuntu libraries, packages and their dependencies) that my programs require to work in the second board; there are near 200 in total so, is it possible to build a Yocto recipe with this list of libraries and packages as input? or there is a way of simplifying the task?
Thank you

Comment: 1. Each Softwareproject should be packed into a recipe

Comment: 1. Each Softwareproject should be packed into a recipe
2. Recipes can have Build- and Runtime dependencies. Use: DEPENDS and RDEPENDS [link](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-DEPENDS)
3.  To install Packages you can modify your local.conf or the image recipe you build. Use IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " a b c"

I would recommend to make an on image recipe. This can be based on a *-base-image given in layer poky. But using that manual you will find how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Create your own images recipe `my-new-image.bb` in your meta-layer like `core-image-minimal.bb`

Add the below lines in your new recipe

```
require core-image-minimal
IMAGE_INSTALL +="package1 package2 package3 package4 ....  "
```

or
you can add all your packages in your `build/conf/local.conf` file

```
IMAGE_INSTALL +="package1 package2 package3 .... package200"
```

if you use

```
 IMAGE_INSTALL_append =" package1 package2 package3 .... package200"
```

you need to give space before `package1` when you use append. for "+=" no need to give space

If you have any libs in your packages you need to give `package1-dev package2-dev etc.,`